# $|a-b|\geq|c|$ and $|b-c|\geq|a|$ and $|c-a|\geq|b|$ Show either a , b or c is the sum of the remaining terms.

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Consider three real numbers $a,b,c$  s.t:

$|a-b|\geq|c|$ and $|b-c|\geq|a|$ and $|c-a|\geq|b|$

Show either a , b or c is the sum of the remainign terms.

I have tried manipulating the inequalities using the triangle inequality , yet i can not get anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**My try :**

because of the symmetry , let's assume W.L.O.G :  $a\geq b\geq c$

We then get :
$$|b+c|\leq|2a| \Longrightarrow \frac{|b+c|}{2}\leq|a|$$

However :

$$|a|\leq |b-c|\leq |b|+|c|$$

So :$$\frac{(b+c)^2}{4} \leq (|b|+|c|)^2$$
$\Longleftrightarrow$
$$3(b^2+c^2+2bc)\leq 0$$
$\Longleftrightarrow$
$$b+c=0$$

But that is clearly wrong.

Comment: You appear to be assuming that $\lvert b\rvert \lvert c\rvert = bc$ but, even so, you would then get $3(b^2 + c^2 + 2bc) \color{red}{\ge} 0$, i.e., your $\le$ should be $\ge$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When any two of $a,b,c$ are equal then the remaining one must be zero
and there is nothing more to prove.

Therefore, W.L.O.G we can assume $c<b<a\,.$ Then, since $c\le |c|\,,a\le |a|\,,b\le|b|$ we get by assumption
$$
c\le a-b\,,\quad a\le b-c\,,\quad b\le a-c\,.
$$
When $c\ge 0$ then we get the contradiction
$$
b<a\le b-c\le b\,.
$$
Therefore, $c<0\,.$ Then, since $|c|=-c$ we get by assumption
$$
-c\le a-b\,,\quad a\le b-c\,,\quad b\le a-c\,.
$$
In particular,
$$
b\le a+c\,,\quad a+c\le b\,
$$
which yields $$\boxed{\quad b=a+c\,\,.\quad}$$

Comment: Very neat , I always find myself struggling when involving absolute values inequalities like this one for example . Any suggestions on some techniques i could approach more often ?

Comment: I think Hardy, Littlewood and Polya wrote a whole book about inequalities but I have to confess that I don't own it. In your question it was the symmetry that I thought will lead to something not so much that boring triangle inequality. One needs luck sometimes.